# Run tasks with error "process unexpectedly exit" in windows

Tags: java, android

I just migrated my project from android 2.2 to 3.2, the first time I opened the project, it build well, closed the project, on reopen am getting this error of 
'Process unexpectedly exit' and run build fails. After so many tutorials it never build so I uninstall android studio completely and install it again and as usual it build and run fine the first time without error. And again after I closed it and reopen, same error "process unexpectedly exit.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post your project level and module level gradle file

Comment: "This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does."